# listview thumbnails repeating c#

Tags: c#, image, listview, repeat

I'm trying to populate a listview box with thumbnails you can select to bring up a preview.

The listview populates with the correct amount of images, tagged with the correct filepath, but the thumbnail for each is a repetition of the first indexed image in the linked imagelist. (see attached code)

```
    private void PopulateList()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp\Snapshots");

        this.listImages.View = View.LargeIcon;
        this.imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(140, 100);
        this.listImages.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;
        int j = 0;

        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
        {                
            try
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                item.ImageIndex = j;
                item.Tag = file.FullName;
                this.imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
                this.listImages.Items.Add(item);
                j = j++;
                //fixed by changing above line to
                //j = (j+1);            
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }            
    }
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, I feel like I'm missing something really simple...

Thanks.

EDIT: Fix in code as comment

Comment: Don't think I've figured it out properly, but did find a workaround:

Changed j = j++ to j = (j+1)

Not sure why that has fixed it...

Comment: The reason that fixes it is because you don't need to perform an assignment when using the postfix operator.  Take a look in at the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx) in MSDN for more details.

Comment: That fixed it because j wasn't changing. You needed to use just `j++;` and not `j=j++;`

Comment: Upvote to negate baseless downvote.

Comment: @Clay, That makes perfect sense, I thought it was just something ridiculous I'd done. Thanks heaps for your input.

Comment: @Ashwin, Thanks to you as well.